# Deployment Completed Status

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When listing pods with ***kubectl get pods*** I get some pods in the status completed, so what does ***Completed*** Status mean for a deployment's pod? not a job but a deployment.

Comment: deployment pods always come with a restart policy "Always", so I doubt these pods from job, not from deployment

Comment: Pleas post the code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

This implies that pods container process has been completed. The pod just stays there so that we could check the logs of the pod.

For more reference check :

[Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)